# How to return top N percent of Pandas DataFrame by grouping?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe df that looks like this:

```
Customer   Revenue  Products  Cluster
Jon         100         5        A
Janet       225         12       C
Jim         75          2        B
Stacy       95          4        A
John        125         5        B
Bob         325         20       C
Megan       75          2        A
Stacy       95          4        A
```

and so on for 100k records.

I am trying to return the top 2 percent of Revenue Customers grouped by cluster.
I know this doesn't work but I think it gives the overall idea of what I am trying to do:

```
df.groupby('cluster').len(df['cluster'])/100 <= .2
```

Trying to get back a dataframe of the top 2 percent of customers by revenue, by cluster.

Comment: What is your desired output for the data shown in the question?

Comment: @cs95 that is exactly it.  I was messing around with sorts and trying to calc lengths and maxes etc...  this is sleek and I knew there was a better way than my approach!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC, it looks like you can use `GroupBy.quantile` and then filter on the result:

```
# "Cluster" is the grouper, and
# "Revenue" is the column to calculate the quantile on. 
df[df['Revenue'] >= df.groupby('Cluster')['Revenue'].transform('quantile', 0.98)]

  Customer  Revenue  Products Cluster
0      Jon      100         5       A
4     John      125         5       B
5      Bob      325        20       C
```